# Consistency of a ratio between positive and negative numbers

Tags: transformation, ratio

I want to model the inverse relationship between two sets of numbers $A, B$ both in the domain $[-5, 5]$. That is, for the same value $A$ I need a number that decreases linearly as $B$ increases, including (and this is the critical point) when $B$ goes from negative to positive. A simple division (ratio) won't work: for example if $A = 5$ and $B=-3$ the ratio is -1.67. But for $B=1$ (higher $B$) the ratio increases to 5.

A simple square transformation won't work either, because both -2 and 2 will assume the same value 4. The ratio should be lower when $B=-2$.

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by ratio of two sets of numbers? $5/(-3)= -1.6\bar{6}$ and $5/(-1) = -5$

Comment: The ratio is simply $A / B$, for all possible values in the domain $[-5, 5]$. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: If you want to calculate a *ratio*, then you'll simply have to accept that the results of your calculations will behave like ratios do, whether you want them to or not. If your actual goal is something different than calculating a ratio, then please try to give a complete and detailed explanation of what sort of thing you're actually trying to do (e.g. how you want the results of your calculation to behave).

Comment: @Hurkyl ok, rephrased to better express the relationship I'm looking to model. btw, does the conventional use of the word ratio makes sense for negative numbers?

Comment: If you want something that increases with $B$, what about $B/A$?

Comment: Ratio makes fine sense for negative numbers. What do you mean by "model the inverse relationship?"  Are you committed to a ratio?

Comment: If you're dividing by $B$, and $B$ is running from negative to positive, then you're going to have a problem when $B=0$.

Comment: @RossMillikan for A held constant, an increasing B must lower the ratio, regardless of its sign

Comment: $f(A,B) = -B$ satisfies your new criterion, as does $f(A,B)=A-B$.

Comment: I fixed the question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: The complete set of possibilities to the new form is $$ f(A,B) = g(A) - h(A) B$$ where $g(A)$ is any function and $h(A)$ is any strictly positive function.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, this works because we are subtracting rather than dividing. But let's say that the two variables have different domains and we do need a ratio to relate them. Is there a transformation or equation that can manage the change in sign?

Comment: There are lots of functions.  You seem fixated on the word ratio-do you mean to be?  Is it required to divide something by something else?  The hard part is defining what you want-finding a function that does that is not so bad.  mweiss gave a very reasonable answer, but there are many more-for starters raise the function to some power, or add a constant, or raise B to a power, or .....

Comment: @RossMillikan many more that preserve the linear relationship? Can you give me an example?

Comment: A linear relationship is very confining, but as mweiss says you can change either or both of the $5$s to any other (larger) number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the commenters that your question is unclear; it seems that you don't know quite what it is you want.  However, I'm going to take a shot at *telling* you what I *think* you want.  Reading between the lines, I think you want some formula that takes as input two numbers $A, B$ and produces as output some number $r$ with the properties that:

1. $r$ is always positive
2. For fixed $A$, you want $r$ to grow linearly as $B$ grows from $-5$ to $5$
3. For fixed $B$, you want $r$ to decrease as $A$ grows from $-5$ to $5$

I think what you basically are trying to say is that you want to "shift" the values of $B$ and $A$ so that instead of using the "true" values (which range from -5 to 5), the "ratio" compares how far $A$ and $B$ are from their minimum values.  If that is what you want, then the formula you need is

$$\frac{B+5}{A+5}$$

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** This formula will still give you trouble if $A=-5$.  If you want to avoid that problem, you could use any formula of the form $\frac{B+n}{A+n}$ where $n>5$.

Comment: I fixed the question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Shifting all the values to positive is ok, but what if I don't know the domain bounds beforehand? Can somehow manage the sign and still calculate a linearly decreasing ratio?

Comment: It seems like what you want is to calculate not $B/A$ but rather $\Delta B / \Delta A$, where $\Delta B$ denotes $B-B_{min}$ and $\Delta A$ denotes $A-A_{min}$.  So I don't think there's any way to do this without knowing the minimum values of your domain.  (The maximum values don't really matter.)

Comment: ok thanks. I'm puzzled about how tricky this can be. I thought this was a very common problem in applied mathematics.

Comment: I think it's only tricky because you don't really know what it is that you want.  As soon as you know exactly what you want, the formula should be pretty straightforward.  I've done my best to help you figure out what you *might* want.